# Configure ESLint rules in create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, create-react-app

I have set up my project to build via `Travis.CI`.  Travis automatically sets the `CI` (environment) variable to true thus causing warnings to be treated as errors during build.

One of my dependencies (`react-mapbox-gl`) is forcing me to violate an ESLint rule, "style prop must be an object (`react/style-prop-object`).

I do not want to disable warnings as errors, but I would like to temporarily disable this one particular rule.

I know that in a regular JavaScript node application `ESLint` rules may be configured in `.eslintrc` or `package.json`.   In create-react-app powered projects however, none of those files seems to have any effect on the build process?

Is there a way to configure ESLint rules in create-react-app without ejecting my `create-react-app`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to disable an `ESLint` rule just for one particular line using a comment:

```
<Map
  // eslint-disable-next-line react/style-prop-object
  style='mapbox://styles/user/hash'
  ...
```

This also works fine for `create-react-app` builds.

For more information see: 
http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring.html#configuring-rules